# Why should I not use a standard loop to access a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I have just started learning C++. I was looking at one example of the Accessing an array and the example was as the following:

```
a[i][j];
*(&a[0] [0]+2*i+j); /* Base address */
*(*(a+i)+j);
```

I am a bit confused about this example. Why can't I just create a standard loop like the following:

```
for(int row=0; row<i; row++ ){
    for(int col=0; col<j; col++ ){
       // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: *I* am confused by that example. Who wrote that wonderfully obfuscated piece of... code?

Comment: You can, the example you're showing was made by someone in the 90's who still thought being able to develop code that nobody can read and is cryptic makes you a better programmer. Your own example is just fine.

Comment: Where did you get this from? Please stop learning from it, whatever it is. :D

Comment: Brief note: put your `Y` loop on the outside. It's faster - can be a LOT depending on your array size - as the iteration will hit consecutive memory locations rather than skipping by the row width every time.

Comment: Well, you can also create a standard loop. Both'll work fine!

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: Indeed, why can't you?

Comment: I recommend wrapping the dynamic array into proper RAII types (ex: `struct dynamic_array { std::unique_ptr<T[]> buffer; size_t size; };` ) and defining `begin` and `end` for those types. After that, you can use higher level range-based algorithms and not worry about how you access data.

Comment: `*(*(a+i)+j);` is much more clearly written as `a[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example lists 3 different methods to access an object at (presumably) the same index in a multi-dimensional array. This is something you would do inside a loop. So either do:

```
for(int row=0; row<i; row++ ){
  for(int col=0; col<j; col++ ){
     auto field = a[col][row];
  }
}
```

OR

```
for(int row=0; row<i; row++ ){
  for(int col=0; col<j; col++ ){
     auto field = *(*(a+col)+row);
  }
}
```

OR

```
for(int row=0; row<i; row++ ){
  for(int col=0; col<j; col++ ){
     auto field = *(&a[0] [0]+2*col+row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to accessing any 1-dimensional array I see 2 standard options:

One of them is the one that your answer contains:

```
a[i]
```

Second one:

```
*(a + i)
```

However, when it comes to two-dimensional arrays, I would use ONLY brackets:

```
a[i][j]
```

Why? Because equivalent of above expression using pointer expressions looks like this:

```
*(*(a + i) + j)
```

Pretty much self-explanatory I guess.

Also you asked about accessing array elements. So I don't really know what the part with loops is about ^^